# How to mount an EFS file system using Docker in Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-efs

Using application version label jenkins-mt-002.zip, which defines a Dockerfile as well as a Dockerrun.aws.json file. The JSON file only contains the volume mapping.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/efs_mount/master/live",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/root/.jenkins"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to map an EFS mount located at /efs_mount on the host system to /root/.jenkins inside of the docker container. I thought I had set it up correctly, but apparently I'm doing something wrong. Could someone take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong?